# How to get rid of cdk-overlay-container

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have an Angular (9.1.4) project, which uses ng-bootstrap (6.1.0) to open dialogs. To my notice, whenever a modal opens, there is `<div class='cdk-overlay-container' />` added to HTML.

Any idea where Angular adds this div, and how to get rid of it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that ng-bootstrap don't create a cdk-overlay. Material Angular do it. The aim is include in this layer the template of the modal, so you can not get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

- Angular material adds the CDK overlay. When you open modals with angular material then it adds  class. Angular adds the modals div in body and not in app-root.

Comment: Thanks Ajinkya! I did doubt that it's related to Angular Material. However my project doesn't use @angular/material. I do use @angular/cdk though.

How to get rid of it?

Comment: Hi, What do want to do with it. Any specific problem it is been causing. You can just overwrite the css in global css in styles.scss. Like in my case angular container was causing issue that my dropdowns were going behind the modal so I increased the z index like .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper, .cdk-overlay-container { z-index: 9999!important; }. You could just overwrite the css in global css

Comment: I did changed css to hide it and even removed it entirely using JavaScript.

Just wonder how it's added in the first place since I didn't use Angular Material, and how to prevent it being added.